# Convert letters to numbers ( a = 1, b = 2...)

Tags: c++

I was trying to convert letters into numbers and it works
example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

What I want is when I input 2 or more letters together it doesn't work
example:

```
abc = 123
```

This is my code right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter Name:"; cin >> name;

    if (name == "A" || name == "a") {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "B" || name == "b") {
        cout << "2" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "C" || name == "c") {
        cout << "3" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "D" || name == "d") {
        cout << "4" << endl; 
    }
    else if (name == "E" || name == "e") {
        cout << "5" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "F" || name == "f") {
        cout << "6" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "G" || name == "g") {
        cout << "7" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `name` to `char` instead of `string`, and then read from `cin` in a loop. Or, simply loop through the characters of the `string`

Comment: What result do you expect if the input is `xyz`?

Comment: It's not working because you are using a string and not going through each character (need a loop).
In addition, you are checking both lower and uppercase and a bunch of if/else statements which can get cumbersome for all 26 letters.
See below for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string word;
cout << "Enter Name:"; cin >> word;
    for(int i=0; i < word.size(); i++){
        std::string name = word[i];
        if (name == "A" || name == "a") {
            cout << "1" << endl;
        }
        ...        
    }
```

This would work

**EXPLANATION**

So basically what a for loop does that it loops through the condition given for eg
`for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){std::cout << i << " ";}` will give a output like this

> 1 2 3 4 5

it basically looped until the `i` is not greater than 5 you can find more info about for loops at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/for-statement-cpp?view=msvc-160

and the other thing `word.size()` will be the string's length

Comment: You probably want `if (word[i] == 'A' || word[i] == 'a')`, no need to create a new string from each letter. Or even better, just do `cout << std::tolower(word[i]) - 'a' + 1;`.

Comment: @super yea ik I wanted it to make it so that the op needs to change only a bit of his code to make it work

Comment: @super: `std::tolower(word[i]) - 'a'` is not portable, work with ASCII but won't work for EBCDIC.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach using ascii values and convert letters to lowercase first.

Explanation: It loops through string and for each character it converts it to lowercase, and then it subtracts the ascii value 96 because lowercase a in ascii is 97. Also note, the program below works fine if your input is letter only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string name;
    cout << "Enter Name: "; cin >> name;

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i)
    {
        cout << tolower(name[i]) - 96 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for the complex if else construct :)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter Name : ";
    std::cin >> name;

    // make name upper, substract value of 'A' then add 1 for each character in the string
    std::transform(name.cbegin(), name.cend(), name.begin(), [](const char c) { return std::toupper(c) - 'A' + 1; });

    for (const auto c : name)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

std::transform loops over the beginning of the name to the end (name.cbegin(), name.cend()), calls a function (the last parameter) for each character in the string and writes the return value into the beginning of the output buffer (3rd parameter). The function I use [](const char c){ ... }. Is a lambda function

Comment: Not sure if the op expects newlines between numbers, but using the string to store the numbers seems fishy to me, especially since you're not gaining any benefits here. `for (auto c : name) { auto asNumber = std::toupper(c) - 'A' + 1; std::cout << asNumber << std::endl; }` yields the same result and iterates through the string only a single time.

Comment: True it is a bit fishy, I should have transformed into an unsigned int array.
Your loop will certainly work :)
And yes I have a tendency to store intermediate results in memory, for later use. But that's not needed here

Comment: @PepijnKramer i dont think the op knows this much of c++ maybe care to explain the code you give

Comment: @Good good point 
std::transform loops over the beginning of the name to the end (name.cbegin(), name.cend()), calls a function (the last parameter) for each character in the string and writes the return value into the beginning of the output buffer (3rd parameter). 
The function I use [](const char c){ ... }. Is a lambda function.

One of my intentions is to show some std library stuff, since it contains solutions for many common problems. And yes I could have written something simpler for beginners